# GWT Celltable Pager not continuing from last showed row

Tags: gwt

I am using a pager with my celltable in GWT .

everything working fine , but there is one issue 
if i have 12 rows in my table .
In the start it shows 1-10  records which is fine .But when i click on the next >
it shows me 2-12 records whereas It should show me 10-12 records . Means in total it should show only 2 records but it is showing 10 records in total.

In the attached image you can see it starts from 2 ,whereas it should start from 11

I am calling the records from server ..
The reason for above is i think that the celltable still have previous (1st 10 ) records in it and it shows these last 8 + the next 2 it just fetched from server.

I tried to use cellTable.setRowCount(0); before cellTable.setRowData(start,result)
but as i do cellTable.setRowCount(0); it goes to addRangeChangeHandler which then again call the server to get the rows from 0 again .

Any idea what could be the solution.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue of the `SimplePager`: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6163

Patches welcome!